# Get xslx and xls file from a folder and copy it in another folder

Tags: c#

I want to download both xlsx and xls file from a folder using c#.I have tried below way:

```
foreach (DriveInfo mydrive in mydrives)
{
    if (mydrive.DriveType != DriveType.Removable)
    {
        if (mydrive.DriveType == DriveType.CDRom)
        {

        }
        if (mydrive.DriveType != DriveType.CDRom)
        {
            var sourceDirectory = mydrive.Name;
            string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(sourceDirectory, "*xlsx");
            foreach (var txtfiles in files)
            {
                string sourceFile = txtfiles;
                string filename = null;
                filename = Path.GetFileName(sourceFile);
                string destinationFile = @"E:\Prog\" + filename;
                File.Copy(sourceFile, destinationFile, true);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

my code only fetches xlsx file i need both xlsx and xls file.

Comment: `*..xlsx` is probably not what you want. Try `.xlsx` or even `*.xls*` since you want both xls and xlsx. That being said, `GetFiles` should not return null. It should return an empty array if no files are found. Double check what directory you're searching. It does not work recursively and will only search the in the folder `sourceDirectory` is specifying.

Comment: To add to my comment, you need the `SearchOption` parameter to search subfolders as well. As your code stands this will search the entire drive which is probably not what you want.

Comment: i need to get the both extwnsions ,anyway to do that with slight change with the existing code.

Comment: Read my comment again. You probably just need to change `*xlsx` to `*.xls*`

Comment: @tmw You are 100% correct IMHO, but you should promote your comment to a full answer copying the OP code and changing it so we can vote for it as the correct answer

Comment: You should only need "*.xls"  this will pick up both.  See the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getfiles?view=netcore-3.1#System_IO_Directory_GetFiles_System_String_System_String_

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(sourceDirectory, "*xlsx");
```

To

```
string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(sourceDirectory, "*.xls");
```

This will match any file that ends in `.xls` or `.xlsx` in `sourceDirectory`.

Comment: You don't need the trailing '*'.  GetFiles isn't a real regex and when given a wild care with a 3 char extension it'll take a 4 char extension that begins with given 3 char extension. (microsoft being microsoft)  So you just need *.xls

Comment: @MikeJ Thanks! I checked the documentation and that's absolute correct. See [Remarks -> Note](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getfiles?view=netcore-3.1#System_IO_Directory_GetFiles_System_String_System_String_System_IO_SearchOption_)

Comment: nothing like microsoft building in some functions for office ;)